# How to inherit/replace a java final class?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, aspectj, hotswap

I'm making a tool to perform several checks in runtime (this is going to be runned in the CI server) and one of the things that I need it's too change implementations of some classes to give the data that I need (basically, I need to know when some specific changes happen in some classes).

This is an OSGi application (I don't know if that's the right name) and I'm using AspectJ to make this information capturing, but AspectJ doesn't change JDK classes and, while I can solve my problem with some classes like LinkedList (not final class with non-final methods), I have to do the same with classes like StringTokenizer or StringBuilder (which I can't inherit or inject code with aspects).

After a few searches I have many questions about HotSwap, custom classloaders and a few other solutions that I've found and I don't know if they're going to satisfy my needs.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (if it's a solution that will just work on the IDE will be fine too) with Java 6

Answer (score 3):

Look at Apache BCEL to manipulate the bytecode of Java Final classes in a convenient way. This way, you can create your own custom classloader, load the class, manipulate the bytecode to include your own checks and then pass the modified class on to your runtime program.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/